# Understanding $\mathcal Z$-transforms and pole locations

Tags: discrete-signals, infinite-impulse-response, impulse-response, transfer-function, z-transform

I am trying to gain a better understanding of pole locations in the $z$-plane of a given discrete transfer function, $H(z)$.  I think I have a pretty good understanding of how to use the $\mathcal Z$-transforms for filter design, but there is something about the core concepts that still confuse me.

I understand that poles are locations in the $z$-plane (complex plane) where a specific value of $z$ results in $\left|H(z)\right|$ approaching infinity.  This happens when the denominator of a $\mathcal Z$-transform expression has a zero at $z=a$.  i.e.

$$
H(z) =\frac{1}{z-0.5} 
$$

would have **one** pole at $z = 0.5$.  The inverse $\mathcal Z$-transform of this fraction would be

$$
h(n) = \mathcal{Z}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{z-0.5}\right\} = 2\cdot0.5^{n-1}
$$

Since $z$ is less than 1, this impulse response will decay as $n$ increases.  So the response is stable (which happens as long as the pole lies within the unit circle).

However, if we look at the definition of the $\mathcal Z$-transform, with $z$ written in complex exponential form, i.e. $z=re^{j\omega}$:

$$
H(z) = H\left(re^{j\omega}\right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} h(n)\left(re^{j\omega}\right)^{-n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} h(n)r^{-n}e^{-j\omega n},
$$

we can now express the $\mathcal Z$-transform for our pole directly using using $z=re^{j\omega}$ with $r=0.5$ and $\omega$=0:

$$
H(0.5) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} h(n)0.5^{-n} = \infty
$$

We know this sum is infinity from our original transfer function.

Now here is where my question begins to form. When $h(n)$ is summed against the $0.5^{-n}$ function, we get an unbounded summation, or a pole.  Of course that can only happen if $h(n)$ is infinite (which it is), since the above summation for $H(0.5)$ could not be infinite otherwise.

But if $h(n)$ is infinite such that it sums to infinity multiplied by $0.5^{-n}$, it would clearly also sum to infinity against $0.58^{-n}$ or $0.25^{-n}$ for that matter.

***So my question is, if there is a pole at 0.5, why aren't there poles all along the real axis (except for zero)?***  Why is there only a pole at 0.5?

To make it explicit, we can use the specific $h(n)$ that was the inverse $\mathcal Z$-transform of $H(z)$, above:

$$
H\left(\frac 14\right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} \left[2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}\right]\cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{-n}
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} 4\cdot 2^n = \infty
$$

So, this sum makes it look like there is a pole at $z=0.25$ for the $\mathcal Z$-transform of $h(n)$, but the transfer function says there is not!

In other words, the single pole makes sense to me looking at the $H(z)$ transfer function, but it doesn't make sense to me when I take it and use it directly in the $\mathcal Z$-transform expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual computation for the inverse Z transform is

$$\frac1{z-0.5}=\frac1z\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{0.5}{z}}=z^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(0.5)^k z^{-k}=\sum_{n(=k+1)=1}^\infty (0.5)^{n-1}z^{-n}$$

From that you see that the series is one-sided, $h(n)=0$ for $n<1$. This should remove most of the infinities that you stumbled upon.

---

Note that this geometric series only converges for $\left|\frac{0.5}{z}\right|<1$, that is $|z|>0.5$. For applications one is only interested in the values of the Z transform on or close to the unit circle, $|z|\approx 1$, the eigenvalues and singular values of the sequence shift operator. The unit circle is clearly and comfortably contained in the region of convergence.

---

So for instance, if the pole were at $z=2$, then the inverse Z transform would again use the Laurent series on and close to the unit circle, i.e., for $|z|<2$, to give

$$\frac1{z-2}=-\frac12\,\frac1{1-\frac z2}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{(-n)-1} z^{-(-n)},$$

that is, $h(n)=0$ for $n>0$ and $h(n)=-2^{n-1}$ for $n\le 0$

Comment: But it doesn't.  Even using your 1-sided expression, take z=1/4, for example:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/2)^{n-1}(1/4)^{-n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2\cdot 2^n
$$

That looks like an infinite sum to me.

Comment: You want to use the Z transform as a short cut to the Fourier series, most of the manipulations with z series are purely formal, algebraic. But in the end, one is only interested in values $z$ on the unit circle. So poles inside the unit circle lead to causal parts of the filter sequence, poles outside to anti-causal parts of the filter sequence.

Comment: True, but it doesn't answer the question. Why is there only one pole at z = 0.5 ?

Comment: z=0.25 is not in the region of convergence, since it is smaller than 0.5. The pole is a pole of the Z transform, a Laurent series that is defined on some small annulus containing the unit circle, in the extremal cases only on the unit circle.

Comment: I think this is the actual answer: The Z transform is not defined outside the region of convergence. It can only be calculated inside the region of convergence.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I do have some vague memories of studying the ROC in school.  I guess I have some reviewing to do.

It looks like this does explain the apparent contradiction I was seeing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to assume that

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2\cdot0.5^{n-1}\cdot a^{-n}}$

is infinite when $a\neq0.5$. This does not appear to be the case. When $a=0.5$, both exponents cancel, the result is always $2\cdot 0.5^{n-1-n}=1$. When $a\neq0.5$, the exponents don't cancel. Instead, you could write:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2\cdot0.5^{n-1}\cdot a^{-n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2\cdot0.5^{n-1}\cdot 0.5^{-n}}\cdot 2^{-n}\cdot a^{-n}=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^{-n}\cdot a^{-n}}
$

Which is finite. I just noticed I'm using the unilateral z-Transform which you don't. In this case I would justify that by the signal having to be causal. The bilateral version appears not to converge anywhere, at all.

Comment: But even using the one sided sum, is it finite for other values? For your expression, let a = 1/4: 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}(1/4)^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n
$$

That sum sure looks like it explodes to me.

Comment: No why? The limit of the sum of a geometric series is finite. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Nope: The sum is only finite, if the argument of the series has a magnitude of less than 1. That's not the case here